# Excel formula for copy data from cells to antother cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need a excel formula for copy data from a column to another column with a conditional situation.
please see below picture:

[image]

I have two columns with eu and ru name. I want to copy "eu" data rows if the header of the first column is "eu" and if I change "eu" to "ru" all data in "ru" copy to the blue part.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Microsoft-365 then could try-

```
=FILTER(E2:F7,E2:F2=B1)
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by a simple `=IF()`, is it not? Like in the example `=IF(D1="eu",A2,B2)`, as in the following screenshot:

[image]

Comment: it is ok for one row, how can extend it for all rows? actually, I do not know the number of rows, each time it can be changed  @Dominique

Comment: You can drag and drop for as much rows as you like.

Answer (score 0):

I find a better solution.( @Dominique )
it is HLookup() formula in excel

[image]

the below link is useful:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/hlookup-function-a3034eec-b719-4ba3-bb65-e1ad662ed95f